# What is the grammatical construct using present progressive in relative clauses called?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, progressive-aspect

When I learned this, it had a very distinctive name and allowed to make more interesting sentences. For instance, given the sentence

> Fred extended his feet, which stopped the car.

It can be rephrased as

> Fred extended his feet, *stopping* the car.

How is this construct called and is the comma still necessary?

Comment: Your first example would imply something like large shoes acting as railway buffers, because *which* naturally goes with *feet* not *extended*.

Comment: @TimLymington: Hmmm, I think you're right, it should read "what", shouldn't it?

Comment: note: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Flintstone

Comment: _Fred extended his feet, which stopped the car_ can't be meaningfully rephrased as _Fred extended his feet, stopping the car_. The meaning of the first sentence is absurd in most cases, & the meaning of the second is now ambiguous. The sentence should probably be: _Fred extended his feet {as / when / before / and (then) [CHOOSE ONE]} he stopped the car_. I would call this replacement of a relative clause by a gerund clause **infernally stupid and annoying**. I almost always change the gerund back to a relative: "..X was > Y, **indicating**..." => "..X was > Y, **which indicated that**...".

Comment: Hi, every so often I go through posts which have "How do you call....?" or "How is/are ______ called?"  in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing your last question to *“**What** is this construct ....?"* Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Stopping the car" is a *present participle phrase*, and it does change the meaning of the sentence in a minor way. In the first sentence, *the extension* of Fred's feet is what stopped the car. (Or, I suppose you could also view it where "which" refers to "his feet," and *his feet* stopped the car.) In the second sentence, *Fred* is what stopped the car (though he clearly did this by *extending his feet*).

The comma is necessary to convey the same meaning in the second sentence. Otherwise, Fred simply extends his "feet stopping the car," which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks to your information I found a [very good site describing how the present participle phrase works](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm).

Answer (score -1):

In your second example, the comma helps clarify who or what is being modified by the participle phrase. In "Fred extended his feet, stopping the car", the comma separates unlike terms. It tells us that *stopping the car* does not modify *feet*. Instead, it modifies another word earlier in the sentence. *Fred*. To remove the comma is to link *feet* and *stopping the car*, to say that *stopping the car* does modify *feet*. And *Fred extended his feet stopping the car* sounds odd because feet don't normally stop cars, brakes do. That is, unless we are talking about Fred Flintstone. In which case, it might be better to say something like:

> Fred extended his feet gouging the dirt and stopping the car.

So, in answer to the question about comma placement with participle phrases, you would be correct with or without the comma, but only because you're talking about the Flintstones.